# Учитывая массив целых чисел, верните новый массив с удвоением каждого значения

Tags: c#, map

Учитывая массив целых чисел, верните новый массив с удвоением каждого значения.

Например:

[1, 2, 3] -> [2, 4, 6]

Для новичков попробуйте использовать метод карты - он очень удобен, поэтому его полезно знать.

```
 public static int[] Maps(int[] x)
  {
    return x;
  }
```

Comment: Вчем заключается проблема ?

Comment: `return x.Select(y => 2 * y).ToArray();`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну, классикой является либо модификация исходного массива:

```
public static int[] Maps(int[] x)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < x.Length; i++)
    {
        x[i] = 2 * x[i];
    }
    return x;
}
```

Либо создание нового:

```
public static int[] Maps(int[] x)
{
    var y = new int[x.Length];
    
    for (int i = 0; i < x.Length; i++)
    {
        y[i] = 2 * x[i];
    }
    return y;
}
```

Ну а если вам надо именно через маппинг, то как-то так:

```
public static int[] Maps(int[] x)
{
    return x.Select(y => 2 * y).ToArray();
}
```

Все три варианта нужно знать, т.к. пригодиться могут любые формы.

Comment: [википедия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)), [en so](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32959468/5752652)